# Viewing all logs in stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I find myself toggling between different 'resources' to view my logs in stackdriver. For example:

[image]

Is there a way to view all combined logs from a single view? Most go to "Global", but many do not as well.

Comment: This is not supported yet. I recommend that you submit a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). Google will consider the need based on its feasibility, or the number of customers who ask for it, but I can't guarantee an implementation or provide you with an ETA for it. Rest assured that Google strives on improving its products and that your feedback helps us do just that

Answer (score 1):

Just convert the filter to advanced view and select the resource types that you need

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource" OR resource.type="gce_instance" OR resource.type="audited_resource"
```

That will show you the logs for bigquery and audit and gce in a single view.

Comment: thanks for this answer -- is there a way to do this in the UI itself?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do textual search across all logs, but it will not be as granular as resource type based search. You can try this with the [Advanced filter feature](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-filters).

On the top right corner of the search box, click the drop down menu and select "Convert to advanced filter". Then delete the "resource.type=xyz" line and type the string you want to search.

As alternative the `gcloud sdk` cli to search the logs without specifying resource type - for instance, `gcloud logging read error --limit 1` would look for "error" string across all your logs and show only 1 matching entry.